# How can I mimic 'select_related' using google-appengine and django-nonrel?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, django-select-related

django nonrel's [documentation](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) states: "you have to manually write code for merging the results of multiple queries (JOINs, select_related(), etc.)".

Can someone point me to any snippets that manually add the related data? @nickjohnson has an [excellent post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine) showing how to do this with the straight AppEngine models, but I'm using django-nonrel.

For my particular use I'm trying to get the UserProfiles with their related User models. This should be just two simple queries, then match the data.

However, using django-nonrel, a new query gets fired off for each result in the queryset. How can I get access to the related items in a 'select_related' sort of way?

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work as I'd expect. Looking at the rpc stats, it still seems to be firing a query for each item displayed.

```
all_profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
user_pks = set()
for profile in all_profiles: 
    user_pks.add(profile.user_id)  # a way to access the pk without triggering the query

users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=user_pks)
for profile in all_profiles:
    profile.user = get_matching_model(profile.user_id, users)


def get_matching_model(key, queryset):
    """Generator expression to get the next match for a given key"""
    try:
        return (model for model in queryset if model.pk == key).next()
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

**UPDATE:**
Ick... I figured out what my issue was.

I was trying to improve the efficiency of the changelist_view in the django admin. It seemed that the select_related logic above was still producing additional queries for each row in the results set when a foreign key was in my 'display_list'. However, I traced it down to something different. The above logic does not produce multiple queries (but if you more closely mimic Nick Johnson's way it will look a lot prettier).

The issue is that in django.contrib.admin.views.main on line 117 inside the ChangeList method there is the following code: `result_list = self.query_set._clone()`. So, even though I was properly overriding the queryset in the admin and selecting the related stuff, this method was triggering a clone of the queryset which does NOT keep the attributes on the model that I had added for my 'select related', resulting in an even more inefficient  page load than when I started.

Not sure what to do about it yet, but the code that selects related stuff is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like answering my own question, but the answer might help others.

Here is my solution that will get related items on a queryset based entirely on Nick Johnson's solution linked above.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_with_related(queryset, *attrs):
    """
    Adds related attributes to a queryset in a more efficient way
    than simply triggering the new query on access at runtime.

    attrs must be valid either foreign keys or one to one fields on the queryset model
    """
    # Makes a list of the entity and related attribute to grab for all possibilities
    fields = [(model, attr) for model in queryset for attr in attrs]

    # we'll need to make one query for each related attribute because
    # I don't know how to get everything at once. So, we make a list
    # of the attribute to fetch and pks to fetch.
    ref_keys = defaultdict(list)
    for model, attr in fields:
        ref_keys[attr].append(get_value_for_datastore(model, attr))

    # now make the actual queries for each attribute and store the results
    # in a dict of {pk: model} for easy matching later
    ref_models = {}
    for attr, pk_vals in ref_keys.items():
        related_queryset = queryset.model._meta.get_field(attr).rel.to.objects.filter(pk__in=set(pk_vals))
        ref_models[attr] = dict((x.pk, x) for x in related_queryset)

    # Finally put related items on their models
    for model, attr in fields:
        setattr(model, attr, ref_models[attr].get(get_value_for_datastore(model, attr)))

    return queryset

def get_value_for_datastore(model, attr):
    """
    Django's foreign key fields all have attributes 'field_id' where
    you can access the pk of the related field without grabbing the
    actual value.
    """
    return getattr(model, attr + '_id')
```

To be able to modify the queryset on the admin to make use of the select related we have to jump through a couple hoops. Here is what I've done. The only thing changed on the 'get_results' method of the 'AppEngineRelatedChangeList' is that I removed the self.query_set._clone() and just used self.query_set instead.

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'user', 'paid')
    select_related_fields = ['user']

    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return AppEngineRelatedChangeList

class AppEngineRelatedChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(AppEngineRelatedChangeList, self).get_query_set()
        related_fields = getattr(self.model_admin, 'select_related_fields', [])
        return get_with_related(qs, *related_fields)

    def get_results(self, request):
        paginator = self.model_admin.get_paginator(request, self.query_set, self.list_per_page)
        # Get the number of objects, with admin filters applied.
        result_count = paginator.count

        # Get the total number of objects, with no admin filters applied.
        # Perform a slight optimization: Check to see whether any filters were
        # given. If not, use paginator.hits to calculate the number of objects,
        # because we've already done paginator.hits and the value is cached.
        if not self.query_set.query.where:
            full_result_count = result_count
        else:
            full_result_count = self.root_query_set.count()

        can_show_all = result_count  self.list_per_page

        # Get the list of objects to display on this page.
        if (self.show_all and can_show_all) or not multi_page:
            result_list = self.query_set
        else:
            try:
                result_list = paginator.page(self.page_num+1).object_list
            except InvalidPage:
                raise IncorrectLookupParameters

        self.result_count = result_count
        self.full_result_count = full_result_count
        self.result_list = result_list
        self.can_show_all = can_show_all
        self.multi_page = multi_page
        self.paginator = paginator
```